# Converting header or text file information to code using Linux/Vim

Tags: linux, parsing, vim, opencl, text-processing

I found myself writing a really simple conversion from OpenCL error codes to a human readable string. The 50 or so different codes are defined in a header file like this:

```
...
#define CL_INVALID_CONTEXT -34
#define CL_INVALID_QUEUE_PROPERTIES -35
#define CL_INVALID_COMMAND_QUEUE -36
#define CL_INVALID_HOST_PTR -37
...
```

I put all of these in a huge switch/case using expert copy/pasting:

```
...
case CL_INVALID_CONTEXT:
  return "CL_INVALID_CONTEXT";
case CL_INVALID_QUEUE_PROPERTIES:
   return "CL_INVALID_QUEUE_PROPERTIES";
case CL_INVALID_COMMAND_QUEUE:
   return "CL_INVALID_COMMAND_QUEUE";
case CL_INVALID_HOST_PTR:
    return "CL_INVALID_HOST_PTR";
...
```

Since I've recently started to use Vim, I am thinking there might be a way to do this in a more efficient way using Linux command tools and Vim. There was a similar post here where someone claimed to have done it with Emacs. Any ideas on how to avoid wasting 15 minutes with a similar task next time?

(I know that *oclErrorSting()* might exist but let's disregard that for generality's sake!)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this in Vim with a search and replace:

```
%s/#define \(\w\+\).*/case \1:^M  return "\1";/g
```

The trick to getting the `^M` in the output is to type `CTRL-V` and then `Enter` where you want put a newline in the output.

This will do the replacement on the entire file.

This works by doing a seach which matches the entire line and replacing it with your desired text.  Each name is captured into a group in the search, that's what the `\(\w\+\)` is doing, then the matched text is used twice in the replacement.

Comment: Thanks, that sounds like exactly what I'm looking for!

Comment: @VictorSand You may use `\r` in replacement string for the newline, not `<C-v><CR>`. To use only on the copy-pasted string paste it, select (mapping like `nnoremap gV "\`[".getregtype(v:register)[0]."\`]"` will be helpful, it selects pasted string if you did not do any edit actions after pasting) and type the above command without leading `%`.

Answer (score 2):

The other generic solution for repetitive tasks is to use `macros`, or complex repeats are they are called in help.

Basically you start recording your inputs in a register, create a single case, and then go to the next line of your define.

See `:help q` for more details.